# strategy for maintaining both native and wcf service layer

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I've got a web application that will sometimes call a service layer from a codebehind as well as call some restful WCF services from clientside code (e.g. JQuery).

I've found that there is a bit of work maintaining both service layers.  I've considered doing away with the native dot.net service layer and using WCF services only, however in my experience this can result in performance that is 4-10x slower due to the web services overhead.

How do the rest of you handle this? Do you manually maintain both layers? Are there practices/tools/frameworks that make this maintenance/synchronization process easier?  Or do you take the performance hit and live solely with a web services layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion that i can give you regarding design of WCF layer is that keep is as thin as possible. The WCF layer should only be responsible for send and receiving data and should be voided of any business functionality\validation. Most of the time it should be delegating work to the service layer. This way maintenance of the service layer is the only major task to take care. WCF wrapper then should be easier to create and maintain. This way you can continue using the old approach with all the performance benefits.